# Jest Test logs an error when I try to use toThrow() on an Async Function (but still passes test)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest to test an async function. So far, I have three tests which seem to be passing.

However, after the tests finish running I get an error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expect(received).toThrow(expected)...`(see full log below). I've tried multiple solutions posted here and on other places like this one on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1700) but I can't get rid of the error.

**I have the following async function:**

```
async function aliasIsAdmin(alias, roles = DEFAULT_ROLES) {
  try {
    const url = "https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/local/xxxxx/";
    if (typeof alias !== "string") {
      throw new Error('Entity "alias" must be a string.');
    }

    if(!Array.isArray(roles)){
      throw new Error('Entity "roles" must be an array but got "' + typeof roles + '". Permission Denied.');
    } 
    else if(roles.some((role) => typeof role !== "string")){
      throw 'Entity "roles" must be an array of strings but got at least one element of type: "' + typeof alias + '". Permission Denied.';
    }

    let { data } = (await axios.get(url + alias)); //Fetch roles that the alias holds.
    return data.some((role) => roles.includes(role)); //If alias has any of the roles in the policy, grant access.

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error when attempting to authorize user @" + alias
      + ". Access for this user has been denied, please try again.\nError:\n" + error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

**And I wrote the following tests:**

```
const { aliasIsAdmin, getRolesByAlias } = require("../authorization");

describe('aliasIsAdmin', () => {
    it('should return true', () => {
        expect.assertions(1);
        return aliasIsAdmin("anAdmin")
        .then((r => {expect(r).toBe(true)}));
      });
    
    it('should return false', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    return aliasIsAdmin("notAnAdmin")
    .then((r => {expect(r).toBe(false)}));
    });

    it('should throw', () => {
        aliasIsAdmin(1)
        .then((r => {expect(r).toThrow('Entity "alias" must be a string.')}));
        });
});
```

**When I run the tests I get:**

```
(node:94497) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expect(received).toThrow(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a function

Received has type:  boolean
Received has value: false
(node:94497) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:94497) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
PASS  public/utils/test/authorization.test.js
  aliasIsAdmin
    ✓ should return true (895 ms)
    ✓ should return false (238 ms)
    ✓ should throw (37 ms)

  console.error
    Error when attempting to authorize user @1. Access for this user has been denied, please try again.
    Error:
    Error: Entity "alias" must be a string.

      41 | 
      42 |   } catch (error) {
    > 43 |     console.error("Error when attempting to authorize user @" + alias
         |             ^
      44 |       + ". Access for this user has been denied, please try again.\nError:\n" + error);
      45 |     return false;
      46 |   }

      at aliasIsAdmin (public/utils/authorization.js:43:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (public/utils/test/authorization.test.js:17:9)
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
```

My test command is: `jest --coverage public/utils/test`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message says `toThrow` expects a function as its received value, in your case it's a promise-resolved boolean value, as you catch all errors in `aliasIsAdmin`'s catch block and return `false`.

If you change your logic in the catch block and re-throw the error, you can use the following in your unit-test:

```
it('should throw', async () => {
      await expect(aliasIsAdmin(1)).rejects.toThrow('Entity "alias" must be a string.');
});
```

If the current logic is correct and you don't actually expect an error to be throw, you need to change your unit-test to check for a resolved `false` boolean value:

```
it('should return false if non-string parameter is passed', async () => {
      const result = await aliasIsAdmin(1);
      expect(result).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean when you suggest changing the logic in the catch-block? Not returning false?

Comment: If you expect an error to be thrown if `aliasIsAdmin` is called with a non-string type, then you have to change it. But you don't have to of course - you can also rewrite your unit-test and check for a resolved `false`-value

Comment: Oh, gotcha! I see my mistake when it comes to logic and what the test is expecting. I'm expecting the function to throw whenever the input is invalid. Isn't this the correct logic? If I wanted to keep the logic to throw, how should I handle it on the catch block? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Couple of ways to do that - you could throw a different/specific error in that case, e.g. `TypeError` (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_typeerror), then in the catch-block rethrow the error if it's an instance of `TypeError` and return false otherwise as you're currently doing.

Comment: Huh, that makes sense. If I throw again in the catch-block I'm basically delegating the Try-catch responsibility to whomever uses the function, correct? BTW if I do it this way, the error goes away... Personally, what do you think of the function `aliasIsAdmin` itself? How would you handle the throw and error handling? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216866/discussion-between-daniel-segura-and-eol).